# Angularjs model not updated when switching between users at login

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angularjs-scope, angularjs-model

I need the following functionality: When a user goes to the login form, the browser should auto fill the username and password.

My implementation works (on FF and Chrome) but, there is this bug (not consistent) where the model data does not get updated correctly when switching between users. This means that I log in with user ONE, then log out, and enter the credentials for user TWO, but after I click the login button, I'm still logged in with user ONE.

The login form looks like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="login(credentials)">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : validationErrors.email}">
            <div class="btn-icon-lined btn-icon-round btn-icon-sm btn-default-light">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="on" ng-model="credentials.email" class="form-control input-lg input-round text-center" placeholder="Email" >
            <span class="help-block" ng-if="validationErrors.email">{{ validationErrors.email.0 }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : validationErrors.password}">
            <div class="btn-icon-lined btn-icon-round btn-icon-sm btn-default-light">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="on" ng-model="credentials.password" class="form-control input-lg input-round text-center" placeholder="Password" >
            <span class="help-block" ng-if="validationErrors.password">{{ validationErrors.password.0 }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-round btn-block text-center">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The login controller contains something like:

```
// Login Controller
app.controller( 'LoginCtrl', ['$rootScope','$scope', '$state', 'AppUser', 'Auth',
    function($rootScope, $scope, $state, AppUser, Auth){

    console.log("LoginCtrl");

    $scope.credentials = {
        "email" : "",
        "password": ""
    };

    $scope.redirectAfterLogin = function() {
        // set user data
        AppUser.setUserData($scope.user);
        ...
    }

    // Login attempt handler
    $scope.login =  function(data) {
        data = {'user':data};

        Auth.login(data,
            function(response) {
                $scope.user = response.data;

                ...

            },function(response){
                $scope.validationErrors = {
                    "email" : [],
                    "password": []
                };
                ...
            }

        );
    };

}]);
```

Logout:

```
// logout
$scope.logout  = function() {
    // remove attempted URL, if any
    AppUser.removeAttemptUrl();

    data =  {'user':
        {
            'email': $scope.user.email
        }
    };
    Auth.logout(data,
        function(){
            AppUser.unSetUserData($scope.user); // se method below
            $state.go(ApplicationState.LOGIN);
        },
        function(){
            console.log("Logout failed");
     });
}

angular.module('app.service').factory('AppUser', [
'$window', '$rootScope', 'LocalStorage', 'appConfig', '$injector', '$location',
function($window, $rootScope, localStorage, appConfig, $injector, $location){

// Redirect to the original requested page after login
var redirectToUrlAfterLogin = { url: '' };
var userKey = "AppUser";
var userData = {};

angular.element($window).on('storage', function(event) {
    if (event.key === userKey) {
        $rootScope.$apply();
    }
});

return {

    /**
     * Redirect to the original requested page after login
     * - we need to be able to save the intended URL, request it, remove it and redirect to it
     */
    saveAttemptUrl: function() {
        if ($location.path().toLowerCase() != ApplicationState.LOGIN) {
            redirectToUrlAfterLogin.url = $location.path();
        }
        else {
            redirectToUrlAfterLogin.url = '/';
        }
    },
    getAttemptedUrl: function() {
        return redirectToUrlAfterLogin.url;
    },
    removeAttemptUrl: function() {
        // re-initialize URL
        redirectToUrlAfterLogin = { url: '' };
    },
    redirectToAttemptedUrl: function() {
        $location.path(redirectToUrlAfterLogin.url);
    },

    /**
     * Returns the current user's state
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    isAuthenticated: function() {
        userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.get(userKey) || '{}').userData;

        if (!this._isSessionExpired()) {
            if (userData !== undefined){
                return !!(userData.id !== null && userData.email);
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            if (userData !== undefined){
                var data =  {
                    'user':{
                        'email': userData.email
                    }
                }

                // we use $injector to avoid Circular Dependency which is thrown by injecting the $api service
                $injector.invoke(['$api', function($api){
                    $api.auth.logout(data).success(function(result){
                        userData = {};
                        localStorage.remove(userKey);
                    });
                }]);
                return false;
            }
        }
    },

    getUserData: function() {
        return userData;
    },

    setUserData: function(data) {
        userData = data;
        localStorage.set(userKey, JSON.stringify({
            userData: data,
            stamp: Date.now()
        }));
    },

    unSetUserData: function() {
        userData = {};

        localStorage.remove(userKey);
    },

    _isSessionExpired: function() {
        var session = JSON.parse(localStorage.get(userKey) || '{}');
        return (Date.now() - (session.stamp || 0)) > appConfig.sessionTimeout;
    },

    userData : userData
};
```

}] );

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Can you add the logout code? I suspect you're not clearing the $scope.credentials.email and $scope.credentials.password anywhere

Comment: What happens when you logout? Sounds like you're not deleting any user data in your AppUser service on logout. Could you please show us your logout code please.

Comment: Sure, I added the logout code.

Comment: You don't seem to have defined the userKey argument in your unSetUserData function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you logout check the `localStorage` with the browser inspector.
Probably you will find some variable that you didn't clear.
So just clear the storage and it should be fine.

To clear the storage use:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

One additional problem it could be you didn't clean the `$rootScope` if you didn't refresh all the data are still in there.

Comment: I have something like this in the locaStorage after logout: AppUser "{"stamp":1436791992992}".

Comment: I used localStorage.clear(); at logout. On the login page (with the login form after logout) when checking the localStorage content, I still have the AppUser: {stamp: 123..} entry.

Comment: Try to put a break point in the inspector to see if you are using the localStorage.clear(); https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Yes, it definitely removes everything from localStorage at logout. But it looks like simply loading the login page adds that stamp value.

Comment: did you clear all the values in $rootScope as well? if you don't refresh the page it's still in there.

Comment: borracciaBlu please update your answer with the $rootScope idea, this is what fixed my problem and I would like to mark my question as answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is this the problem? `userKey` doesn't seem to be defined in the code you've showed.

```
// add userKey param
unSetUserData: function(userKey) {
    userData = {};

    localStorage.remove(userKey);
},
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code, I didn't think to add that. I have a service defined: angular.module('sgApp.service').factory('AppUser', [... that handles all the user related functionality. The problem, I believe, is somewhere in the logic (I have no errors in the console and the login/logout has been working for months now).

Comment: It would be easier if we could see the code in full rather than edited versions. Could we see an unedited version of your AppUser service for example?

Comment: Sure, I added the complete AppUser service to my question.